# Gmail api service starting from access token

Tags: python, gmail-api, stormpath

I have an access token, that I got from authenticating through StormPath. Looking at the [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python), I would like to get a 'service' object, to which I can start making requests, a la:

```
service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
```

My problem is that in the flow demonstrated in the docs, my access token seems irrelevant, i.e. I cannot see where one is being used. The flow requests and then builds with credentials. But if I do everything that's in the quickstart, then why did I go to the trouble of getting a token in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

The [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) tutorial on Google's documentation does fetch the access token for you, so if you intend to use that sample application you *don't* need to get the access token a second time, using Stormpath.

Stormpath's web framework integrations will do the access token work for you, but it's not required.  Regardless of how you obtain the access token, you can post it to your Stormpath application (this is usually done via an `application.getAccount()` method in our libraries).  This will create an account object for the user in your Stormpath directory, and use the access token to fetch the user's data from Google.

You can continue to store the access token in your own system, to make calls to the Gmail API on behalf of the user.

Comment: Re: it fetches it for you -- my confusion is I can't see _where_. Is it inside "credentials"? And I went down the getAccount path, but all I saw were Stormpath objects, and I wasn't sure how they translated into the 'service' I saw in the quickstart. I'm having trouble briding the gap between Stormpath's docs, and google's. What call do I make on the stormpath account to get a google object? (Starting with what's returned from `get_provider_account` -- that's as far as I got.)

Comment: Their example redirects you away to the Google login form, and then it appears to save the credentials in a file when you return.  This appears to be hidden behind an imported api.  Regarding Stormpath, can you link me to the documentation that you are reading? That will help my tailor my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: The Stormpath docs I'm pulling from (for that call) are [here](http://docs.stormpath.com/python/product-guide/#accessing-accounts-with-google-authorization-codes-or-an-access-tokens). Inspecting the returned object, it just wasn't clear what the next step was.